# Why does it say x is not defined?

Tags: python, function

So i'm trying to type what i consider a very simple code and it works perfectly.

```
def func():
    x=int(input("enter first number:"))
    y=int(input("enter second number:"))
    return x / y

print(func())
```

Then i try putting in parameters for my functions

```
def func(x,y):
    x=int(input("enter first number:"))
    y=int(input("enter second number:"))
    return x / y

print(func(x,y))
```

and then it "name 'x' is not defined" (I'm quite sure it would say `y` too but `x` came first) Why is this so?

I did mention `x = int(input)` so why is it not defined? And if this is the case should i just avoid declaring parameters in future? Sorry if this is a dumb question i'm still learning.

Comment: In the second example, you're passing `x` and `y` to your function invocation, but it's not clear where you expect Python to pull those values from when you haven't defined them yet. They're defined in your function, but that isn't in the same scope as your function call nor has it been executed yet.

Comment: you need to define x and y value outside the function in 2nd code..

Comment: Why did you put parameters in the first place if the function doesn't use them? Maybe you meant to move the `input`s outside the function?

Comment: @wjandrea is it considered using the function if its stated in the function x=int(input("enter first number:"))?

Comment: @DavidTan Sorry, "using the function"? What do you mean? Maybe "using *them* in the function"?

Answer (score 0):

Your **1st code will execute** cause in this function it does not require any parameter (i.e. value) **while calling the function** but in 2nd code you make the *function parameterized*. Hence **you need to give value at the function calling**

One way you can do is:

```
def func(x, y):
    return x / y

print(func(int(input("enter first number:")), int(input("enter second number:"))))
```

2nd way:

```
def func(x, y):
    return x / y

a = int(input("enter first number:"))
b = int(input("enter second number:"))
print(func(a, b))
```

Output [both codes]:

```
enter first number:4
enter second number:5
0.8
```

Comment: I just edited your post to improve it and I moved the inputs in the process. Maybe it's not a big deal, but personally I find it easier to follow code if you have the static stuff like function definitions before dynamic stuff like inputs.

Comment: Thanks for the improvement :) @wjandrea